# Edition of Publication in metadata, EPUB 3.0, content.opf

Tags: metadata, epub

I got this from the customer:

Metadata are actually contained in the docuemnt in legible form. Metadata include

- Title(it is in the cover page and on page 1)
- Language(language in which the document is written)
- EDITION OF THE PUBLICATION(it is on page i, History section)
- Keywords(they are on page i. Do not add any keywords if there is no list on page i)

I covered the first 2 requirements but there's no way I could find out where to put that Edition of the Publication within content.opf document. What is the metadata tag where I should put that Edition of the Publication?
Here is how the Edition(listed or not listed) looks like:

[image: Pdf vs content.opf]

I also have pdf files with the Edition not listed:

[image: Russian Image History Not Listed]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Metadata differs somewhat between EPUB 2.0 and 3.0, so I'm not entirely sure if you'll be able to do this with that example.  That said, here's how it can be done with EPUB 3.0 files:

```
<dc:title id="t1">Main Title</dc:title>
<meta refines="#t1" property="title-type">main</meta>
<meta refines="#t1" property="display-seq">1</meta>
<dc:title id="t2">Subtitle</dc:title>
<meta refines="#t2" property="title-type">subtitle</meta>
<meta refines="#t2" property="display-seq">2</meta>
<dc:title id="t3">Second Edition</dc:title>
<meta refines="#t3" property="title-type">edition</meta>
<meta refines="#t3" property="display-seq">3</meta>
<dc:title id="t4">Main Title: Subtitle. Second Edition.</dc:title>
<meta refines="#t4" property="title-type">expanded</meta>
<meta refines="#t4" property="display-seq">4</meta>
```